# How to set @Url.Content parameter in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In a jquery function I want to set a jquery variable to Url.Content in MVC 5 razor view. 
I have tried the code sample below but it gives an error - "The name 'jsLink' does not exist in the current context".

```
var jsLink = "~/Uploads/01.jpg";
var imageurl = '@Url.Content(jsLink)';
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you can't use a javascript variable as an .net variable.

Comment: This is because jsLink is JavaScript variable whose scope is only on client side I.e. on browser. But @Url.Content runs on iis server.  You need to write like this.. '@Url.Content( "~/Uploads/01.jpg")';

Comment: When @Url.Content() is running, the javascript is not yet existing.

Comment: Whats wrong with var jsLink = "/Uploads/01.jpg"; ?

Comment: @AndersLindén image is not shown with "/Uploads/01.jpg"

Comment: So where is the Uploads directory?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are looking for the base URL of a virtual folder by invoking URL.Content. What I have done in the past is something like this:

```
var rootURL = document.location.hostname;
alert(rootURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@Html.Raw(Url.Content(jsLink))` or the link will be html encoded, and will break the link.